# sheet array subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am creating a macro which will select sheets from a larger workbook, move and save those sheets as a new workbook, and then move onto the next set.

I have created a pseudo "array" with start and end values (designated by sheet index numbers).

I am encountering a "Subscript out of range" error after completing the section that saves the file, but before the loop which would pull the next set of worksheets.

Below is my code. Any help with this error would be appreciated.

```
Dim Start As Integer
Dim Finish As Integer
Dim SR As Integer  
Dim SC As Integer
Dim ER As Integer
Dim EC As Integer
SR = 2
SC = 5
ER = 2
EC = 6
Start = Sheets("REF").Cells(SR, SC).Value
Finish = Sheets("REF").Cells(ER, EC).Value
Dim sheetArray() As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer
i = 0
c = Start
lastrow = Cells(100, SC).End(xlUp).Row

Do Until SR = lastrow

    Do Until c > Finish
        ReDim Preserve sheetarray (0 to i)
        i = i + 1
        c = c + 1
    Loop

    Sheets(sheetarray).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

    C = Start
    i = 0
    SR = SR + 1
    ER = ER + 1
Loop
```

EDIT: 16:35 Central US

Currently, the relevant code block matches what is above, through the line `lastrow = Cells(100, SC).End(xlUp).Row`

Do Until SR = lastrow

```
ReDim sheetArray(i)

Do Until c > Finish
    ReDim Preserve sheetArray(i)
    sheetArray(i) = c
    i = i + 1
    c = c + 1

Loop



Sheets(sheetArray).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    XXXXXXXXXXXXX

c = Start
i = 0
SR = SR + 1
ER = ER + 1
```

`Loop`

Comment: sheet indexes start at 1

Comment: what line gives you an error?

Comment: I am getting the error at line "Sheets(sheetarray).copy", but after it runs through the loop once, creating the first workbook.

Comment: And when I change the 0 to a 1 in "ReDim Preserve sheetarray (0 to i), I get an "Subscript out of range" error on that line, before generating the workbook.

Comment: you need to release the original values loaded to `sheetarray` before trying to create it again before starting another loop

Comment: Scott,

How would I do that?  From what I could find researching, nothing seemed to work/resolve my error.  I have attempted the various codes on [This Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zyeke9(VS.80).aspx), inserted after the file is created/saved, and have not resolved my issue.

Comment: I will post an answer, that I think will work. Test it and if not, let me know.

Comment: I have solved my issue.  After my VBA was running, it was then looking in the active book (which was the newly created book).  Having not found the values it was looking for, it threw an error.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need three things here:

1. ReDim the array before you load each sheet index because the way you have it now it will just keep building on each loop and thus you will get the `Subscript out of range` error starting at the second loop - because the array basically has, as an example, `1 3 5` from first and then `1 3 5 3 7`, with `1 3 5` from first then `3 7` from second.
2. To set the value of the array each time. You only set the elements of the array
3. Qualify which workbook to copy the sheets from, because each time you copy the sheets it sets the active workbook to the newly copied workbook.

Build your `Do Loop` block like this:

```
Do Until SR = lastrow

    ReDim sheetArray(0) 'or you can put i here since you set it to zero at the bottom

    Do Until c > Finish

        ReDim Preserve sheetArray(i)
        sheetArray(i) = c

        i = i + 1
        c = c + 1

    Loop

    Workbooks("myWkb").Sheets(sheetArray).Copy 'where myWkb is the workbook name you need ... you can also use ThisWorkbook (meaning the workbook where the code is running) but this is not best practice
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

    c = Start
    i = 0
    SR = SR + 1
    ER = ER + 1

Loop
```

Comment: I believe I am still getting the same error.  I changed my code after "lastrow = Cells....(xlUp).Row" to match what you posted, and I am getting the same error on the same line.

Additionally, it will now not completed the loop the first time to create the one file I was getting before.

Comment: make sure your variable types match up (double vs. integer, etc.)

Comment: I believe that my variable types match up, unless my `sheetArray` should not be a double?  I attempted changing to integer, as well as changing `i` and `c` to double to match the array, and am still encountering the same error on the same line.

Comment: yeah, I just realized that you never load any values into sheetArray ... you only set how many elements will be in the array. You'll need to define what values goes into each array ... see my edited answer ... I would also set everything to integer, so its all you need based on what you are working with. you can `sheetArray(i) = c` to substitute whatever goes in there if `c` is not correct.

Comment: I am back to being able to generate the first book, but I am still encountering the same error as before.  I also changed my array to integer instead of double.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I know what it is. You need to qualify your workbook in the `Sheets(sheetArray).Copy` line. WHen you copy the sheets, it moves the `ActiveWorkbook` to that copied workbook and tries to set the select the array based on that workbook and you want it to use the workbook where the code runs. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I have solved my issue.  After my VBA was running, it was then looking in the active book (which was the newly created book).  Having not found the values it was looking for, it threw an error.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As I could see it, the problem is that you are just adjusting the dimension of your `sheetArray`, but you are not putting anything inside. So basically, the values inside the array are all zeros. Then you are asking Excel to copy sheets(0), which is out of range because sheet numbers start at 1.

You can fix this by writing inside your array the indices of the sheets you want to copy:

```
Do Until c > Finish
    ReDim Preserve sheetarray (0 to i)
    sheetarray(i) = c ' <~~~~ or something else, according to your goal
    i = i + 1
    c = c + 1
Loop
```

p.s.: It is better to make sheetArray an array of Integer (not Double), since its elements are indices of sheets...However, even with doubles it should work if the array's contents are set properly.

Comment: I am once again encountering the same problem on the same line, with failure to generate the first book I was getting before with my "broken" code.

Comment: @A.Hayes can you please post the adjusted code? I am not sure what indices you are putting or want to put inside the array. However if you put inside it some existing indices, I am sure it should work because I tested it :)

Comment: @A.Hayes I suggest that you verify the existence of each sheet index you put inside the array, just by adding `Debug.Print Sheets(c).Name` right after `sheetArray(i) = c`. This way you can verify if what goes inside the array are correct values.

Comment: I have solved my issue.  After my VBA was running, it was then looking in the active book (which was the newly created book).  Having not found the values it was looking for, it threw an error.  Thank you for the help.